# SpringBoot auto trim spaces in the @RequestParam list if there is only 1 parameter is provided

Tags: spring-boot, http-request-parameters

I have a REST API which supports filtering by multiple values:

```
@GetMapping("/employees")
public ResponseEntity<List<Employee>> getAllEmployees(
            @RequestParam(name = "role", required = false) List<String> roles) {

}
```

Call this API this provided information: /employees?role= ADMIN
then List roles will have 1 element:

- role=ADMIN
  (without the headinng space)

But when I call this API with multiple roles: /employees?role= ADMIN&role=STUDENT
then roles will have 2 elements:

- role= ADMIN (with the heading space)
- role=STUDENT

How can I avoid this auto-trimming spaces here?

Thanks

Comment: Did u try to URL encode before making the API call? Or you do the call via a ready client (e.g. Postman)?

Comment: I called this API via Postman

Answer (score 1):

you can try this instruction  inside your mehtod to auto trimming space in your list

```
List<String> rolesWithoutSpaces = roles.stream().map(String::trim).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply make your call like that,

```
/employees?role= ADMIN,STUDENT
```

Since the values are comma-separated, Spring Controller will interpret them as two different values of the `List<String> roles` by default.

If you then print them inside your controller, you will see that any blank space is auto-trimmed.

Did that `for (String s : roles) System.out.println("Role :" + s);` inside the controller and my logs are,

```
Role :ADMIN
Role :STUDENT
```